# Why is CORS disabled my WebSocket connection

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, cors

i'm developping a website where an admin can pull by dashboard.php a new .JPG to his website localhost:8000/index.php .
To do this i use server.JS with Node.JS:

```
const app = express();
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:8000', // Remplacez par le domaine de votre application cliente
  methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  credentials: true, // Autoriser les cookies et les en-têtes d'autorisation
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(server);

// Serveur WebSocket
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('Un client s\'est connecté');

    // Écoute les changements dans le dossier "Images"
    fs.watch('Images', { recursive: true }, (eventType, filename) => {
        if (eventType === 'change' || eventType === 'rename') {
        // Émet un événement 'imageUpdated' aux clients connectés
        io.emit('imageUpdated', { filename });
        }
    });

  // Gérer la déconnexion du client
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Un client s\'est déconnecté');
  });
});

// Serveur HTTP pour l'application web
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Serveur HTTP démarré sur le port ${PORT}`);
});
```

And i introduice in the index.php a script that connect the WS together to automaticly reload the page even if client is connected on the website at the same time admin pulling the new picture.

```
    // Connexion WebSocket côté client pour les utilisateurs
    const socket = io('http://localhost:3000'); // Mettez à jour l'URL du serveur WebSocket

    // Écoute des événements 'imageUpdated'
    socket.on('connect', (e) => {
        console.log('connecté' + e);
    });

    socket.on('imageUpdated', (data) => {
        console.log('Image mise à jour:', data.filename);

        // Commentez ou supprimez la ligne suivante pour éviter le rechargement automatique
        // location.reload();
    });
```

In the dev console i get these errors by pair. It comes every 2-3 sec and saying this
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OpMMY25' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`
`GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OpMMncX net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)`

THANKS YOU ALL FOR READING THIS

Try to make CORS option.
Try to check if the WS connected but no

Comment: You have port 3000 in one place and port 8000 in another, and no header with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Comment: @some I add this `app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8000');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});`
But nothing change. Futhermore, i don't understand why port is important. WS speak through 3000 event if the php where it is use 8000 .

Comment: Did you try to add both localhost addresses to the cors origin?
For me it seems like you have to add both of them to the origin, because of your client (localhost:8000) and your websocket (localhost:3000) want to communicate with your server? So you have to allow the communication with the cors oirigin property.

Comment: @devhubmarius the only websocket in the php files wants to communicate with the server.js host in localhost:3000. So i don't think it's about that. But if you think let me know how to add 2 url to ACAO .

Comment: If just your websocket is communicating with your server than you have to add `http://localhost:3000` to the origin instead of `http://localhost:8000`. In Case you need more domains as origin you can write const `corsOptions = { origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:8000']}`

Comment: @devhubmarius i use with code 
`const cors = require('cors'); 
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const corsOptions = {
  origin: ['http://localhost:8000','http://localhost:3000'], // Remplacez par le domaine de votre application cliente
  methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  credentials: true, // Autoriser les cookies et les en-têtes d'autorisation
};`
But nothins change same error in the console ;-;

Comment: Can you add a picture of the Response Headers in dev console from the request, which triggers this error? Also please at your require statements to your files.

Comment: @devhubmarius this is the screenshot you ask if i understand correctly : https://imgur.com/a/RIvBMWP

Comment: Ok perfect. When you look into the Response Headers there are no headers for `Access-Control-Allow-`. This means your server does not use `cors` as middleware. Lets enable the `cors` for your `io` server like this:
`const io = socketIO(server, {  cors: {origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  credentials: true}});`

Can you now have a look into the Response Headers again, Did you see headers with `Access-Control-Allow-`?

Docu: https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/

Comment: Or change the origin to `http://localhost:8000`, when `:3000` does not work.
In addition  remove the line `app.use(cors(corsOptions))` in your code. It has no effect in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @devhubmarius he find the solution :

the thing is that cors where needed as middleware like :

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors());

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(server, {cors: {origin: 'http://localhost:8000',   methods: ['GET', 'POST'],   credentials: true}});
```

the header response : https://imgur.com/a/XuubnTc

So it work well
Thanks !